# how to change event listener in a child component from other child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

- *`bbb.js` is the parent component*
- *it has component `ccc` with prop `aaa`*
- *component `ccc` has component `ddd`*
- `aaa.js` has `onFocus()`, `onBlur()` methods in it
- `ddd.js` has `Event Listener`, `document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown)`

Now, How to `Enable/Disable` event listeners from `onFocus()` and `onBlur()` events.

<sup>***I'm just asking idea here not code. In the event that anybody gave a code test I generously appreciate there endeavors.***</sup>

Comment: My view on this is to make a state (`isFocused`) and maintain it in a global store (use redux may be). So, you can toggle the state from `aaa.js` and use it in `ddd.js` to either perform an operation inside the listener or not. It will not enable/disable the listeners though, we can silence it by checking the `isFocused` value.

Comment: Another approach which I used because redux is not suited for "transient" events like "button clicked", is use an EventEmitter. In `onFocus`, emit `disableOnClick`, and in the other component, listen for this event and then disable the click event.

Comment: @TusharShahi how can i pass Props from `aaa` it's a child component and it can only receive props.

Comment: @vinay-deshmukh can u please give some more details. I couldn't able to understand what you said.

Comment: Sorry, i misread the diagram. You can follow this to call affect state of parent from child. Follow this example from React docs, lifting state up https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010